# Why won't my simple LESS file compile in Kademi?

Tags: html, css, less, kademi

I'm trying to use LESS files on the Kademi platform so it compiles server side instead of in the browser, I have this tag in my normal.html file:

```
<link href="/theme/assest/less/main.less" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Is there a way to find out why it's not compiling?

Comment: What other less files are declared in the header? Can you see what the final compiled link is in the generated page?

Comment: `<link href="/theme/assets/less/main.less" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />`

        `<link href="/theme/theme-params.less" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />`

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='/theme/--theme--theme-params.less,.compile.less?-2139071231'/>`
`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='/theme/--theme--assets--less--main.less,.compile.less?-2139071231'/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the problem looks like main.less has a different media type to the other less files. The platform has combined less files to compile them, but main.less is probably missing parameters defined by the other .less files

So to solve the problem you can either

- change the media type for main.less to 'all'
- add an @import to main.less to include other less files with the necessary parameters for it to compile

Comment: I changed my media type to 'all' and it worked! Thank you :-)